# How to refactor repeated code using reflection

Tags: c#, linq, generics, azure, reflection

So I have this large switch statement which is essentially the same code repeated multiple times where the only thing changing is the cast to a specific class. I've been trying to figure out a way to refactor it using reflection so I only have to write it once.

```
switch(provider)
{
               case SocialNetworks.Linkedin:
                    {
                        List<Linkedin> profiles = await MobileService.GetTable<Linkedin>().Where(p => p.uuid == (obj as Linkedin).uuid).ToListAsync();
                        if (profiles.Count == 0)
                        {
                            await MobileService.GetTable<Linkedin>().InsertAsync(obj as Linkedin);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case SocialNetworks.Facebook:
                    {
                        List<Facebook> profiles = await MobileService.GetTable<Facebook>().Where(p => p.uuid == (obj as Facebook).uuid).ToListAsync();
                        if (profiles.Count == 0)
                        {
                            await MobileService.GetTable<Facebook>().InsertAsync(obj as Facebook);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case SocialNetworks.Twitter:
                    {
                        List<Twitter> profiles = await MobileService.GetTable<Twitter>().Where(p => p.uuid == (obj as Twitter).uuid).ToListAsync();
                        if (profiles.Count == 0)
                        {
                            await MobileService.GetTable<Twitter>().InsertAsync(obj as Twitter);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
}
```

Note that here `obj` is of type `Object` and `MobileService` is of type `MobileServiceClient` which is part of the Windows Azure Mobile Service library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering on original question how to rewrite this in generic way with reflection, so that method should not require changes for every new social network.

If MySpace gonna be handled, you need just to add it to *handlerMapping*, HandleAnySocialNetworkByMapping() not changing (see code below).

```
class Program
{
    private readonly static Dictionary<SocialNetworks, Type> handlerMapping = new Dictionary<SocialNetworks, Type>()
                                                          {
                                                              {SocialNetworks.Linkedin, typeof(Linkedin)},
                                                              {SocialNetworks.Facebook, typeof(Facebook)},
                                                              {SocialNetworks.Twitter, typeof(Twitter)},
                                                          };
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HandleAnySocialNetworkByMapping(SocialNetworks.Facebook, new Facebook()).Wait();
        HandleAnySocialNetworkByMapping(SocialNetworks.Linkedin, new Linkedin()).Wait();
        HandleAnySocialNetworkByMapping(SocialNetworks.Twitter, new Twitter()).Wait();
    }

    private async static Task HandleAnySocialNetworkByMapping(SocialNetworks provider, object socialNetwork)
    {
        Type handler = handlerMapping[provider];
        var insertIfNotExistsMethodInfo = typeof(SocialRepository)
            .GetMethods()
            .First(m => m.Name == "InsertIfNotExists");
        await (Task)insertIfNotExistsMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(handler).Invoke(new SocialRepository(), new[] { socialNetwork });  
    }
}
```

where
**SocialRepository** constains persistance logic

```
public class SocialRepository
{
    public async Task InsertIfNotExists<TEntity>(TEntity obj) where TEntity : Social
    {
        var profile = await MobileService.GetTable<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault(p => p.uuid == obj.uuid);
        if (profile == null)
        {
            await MobileService.GetTable<TEntity>().InsertAsync(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

**Entities**

```
    public abstract class Social { public Guid uuid { get; private set; } }    
    public class Linkedin : Social{/*...*/}
    public class Twitter : Social{/*...*/}    
    public class Facebook : Social{/*...*/}

    public enum SocialNetworks
    {
        Linkedin,
        Facebook,
        Twitter
    }
```

Comment: I like this solution and I think it may work. The only issue I've been having (which is what I was worried about when have a common base class) between the Social Network classes is that when it won't save to the database base the `uuid` field from the base class isn't being serialized with the specific class instance when I try the `InsertAsync` operation

Comment: Sounds like serialization issue. Did you mark base class with DataContract attribute and "uuid" property with DataMember attribute?

Comment: I've never used DataContracts before, I'll give that a try later today and see if that works

Comment: Nevermind, using the DataContract attribute made the Azure Mobile Services not recognize the instance of the class, but it turns out the solution was more simple than that. You wrote `if (profile == null)` when it should be `if (profile.Count == 0)` which fixed it. But other than that this solution works great!

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this without using reflection by creating a function that takes in a generic type parameter. A simple example would be:

```
public List<T> SomeFunction<T>()
{
    return new List<T>();
}
```

Then call it like:

```
var list = SomeFunction<FaceBook>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, assuming that your `Facebook`, `Twitter` and `Linkedin` classes inherit from the base class `SocialNetwork`.

```
void FunctionX(SocialNetworks provider, object obj)
{
    switch(provider)
    {
               case SocialNetworks.Linkedin:
                    {
                        FunctionY<Linkedin>(obj as Linkedin);
                        break;
                    }
                case SocialNetworks.Facebook:
                    {
                        FunctionY<Facebook>(obj as Facebook);
                        break;
                    }
                case SocialNetworks.Twitter:
                    {
                        FunctionY<Twitter>(obj as Twitter);
                        break;
                    }
    }
}

void FunctionY<T>(SocialNetwork obj)
{
    List<T> profiles = await MobileService.GetTable<T>().Where(p => p.uuid == (obj).uuid).ToListAsync();
    if (profiles.Count == 0)
    {
        await MobileService.GetTable<T>().InsertAsync(obj);
    }
}
```